# How does JWSTs ISIM direct light into its detectors?

Tags: spacecraft, space-telescope, james-webb-telescope

I came across this diagram in the [JWST User documentation](https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/jwst-observatory-hardware/jwst-observatory-coordinate-system-and-field-of-regard) which explains how light is directed into the ISIM (Integrated Scientific Instrument Module):

[image: Diagram of JWST OTE optics]

But the ISIM contains four detectors (MIRI, NIRCam, NIRSpec and NIRISS), How does the ISIM split this beam for each detector?

Comment: Different telescope, different SE site and different question but some similar-looking diagrams; [Where exactly is the modification that first corrected the spherical aberration in Hubble's primary mirror?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27912/7982)

Comment: If those 4 cameras study different $\lambda$ ranges, then spectral filter-beamsplitters are used.  If they study the same ranges, or overlapping ranges, then almost certainly there are some flip-in mirrors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [this report](https://www.jwst.nasa.gov/resources/ISIMmanuscript.pdf) which includes this drawing:

[image]

The report contains a bunch of tables describing the wavelength bands, filter paths, etc. Note particularly the "Dichroic Beamsplitter"

PostScript: several nice references on the Wikipedia page for ISIM

Comment: That diagram is showing the inside of NIRCam, 1 of the JWST instruments, which comes *after* the ISIM. Those beamsplitters split the NIRCam imaging beam into short (0.6-2.3um) and long (2.4-5um) wavelength channels [ref]( https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/near-infrared-camera/nircam-observing-modes/nircam-imaging). The ISIM seems to use pickoff mirrors to direct different bits of the OTE beam into the different instruments as shown in [this FOV layout](https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/jwst-observatory-hardware/jwst-field-of-view) - not found an ISIM optical diagram yet..

Comment: @astrosnapper I don't see anything in that  Image-Plane layout drawing which suggest pickoff mirrors, or for that matter upstream dichroics or other splitter/separator elements. It's purely showing the ultimate placement of sensors in the main telescope's FOV

Comment: I agree, the only clue is that none of the instruments are on axis and brief references in the caption of Fig 2 on [this page](https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/jwst-observatory-hardware/jwst-telescope), the Gardener et al 2008 ref and other instruments such as [NIRSS](https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/near-infrared-imager-and-slitless-spectrograph/niriss-instrumentation/niriss-optics-and-focal-plane) to pick-off mirrors (and as the first element in your posted NIRcam diagram). All beamsplitters would be in the instruments, ISIM (optically at least) is just pickoff mirrors around the telescope pupil